# Where in iOS 8 do I customize the notification centre?

Tags: settings, notifications, iphone

For some reason I cannot find Notification Centre section on my iPhone 6.

It's where you can set the today view to appear on lock screen, etc. I set it up a long time ago (probably in iOS 7), and I think there used to be a "Notification Centre" section in Settings. Now All I see is:

-Notifications (control notifications from apps)
-Control Centre
-Do Not Disturb

Where did it go? I searched online and tried to find it myself but it's taking too much time. Can anyone help?

[image: my iPhone settings]

Comment: The answer to this question seems so obvious that (it even seems to answer itself) that I'm guessing that `settings` > `notification center` is not what you are looking for.  Try this, pull down the notification center , make sure you are on the `today` tab and then scroll all the way to the bottom and hit the `edit` button... is this what you are looking for?  Widget inclusion and ordering options? (note: the phone must be unlocked first for the edit button to appear)

Comment: It was **so** obvious, I've never seen it… will scrap my answer.

Comment: Tyson, settings > notification centre is exactly what I am looking for. Where is it???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after searching on the web for some more, I found it: they moved it under "Touch ID & Passcode"

The details are outlined here.

http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/ios-8-apple-moves-setting-notification-center-on-lock-screen

–––

To give you some more details:

When the phone is unlocked and you pull down the notification centre, you can swipe to the right to see the today summary and widgets (this applies to everyone). However, when the phone is locked, there was an option to display 1) nothing (you can't pull down the notification view), 2) today view only, 3) notification view only, or 4) both. This is different depending on how the user set up their phone.

I initially set up my phone such that only "notification view" would be accessible on the lock screen. This means that when my phone is locked and I pull down the notification centre, it will only show notification view, and I cannot swipe to the right to see the "today view". It looks like as though "today view" doesn't exist at all. But I wanted to change that, and I got confused because "notification centre" section was taken out altogether from Settings.

Anyhow, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Make certain your phone is unlocked and pull down the notification center.  When on the 'today' tab and unlocked, there is an 'edit' button at the bottom of the notification center that allows you to adjust what content is displayed and what order it is displayed.

Answer (score -1):

I found it !

General > accessibility > zoom .. Then turn it off. then.. swipe down and see

Comment: Hi Fa3el 5eir, welcome to Ask Different. Your answer does not seem to address the problem described by the OP. Please complement it or explain how it may help solve it. Thanks!